# How to edit the manifest inside a .APK file

Tags: android, android-manifest

Somebody knows a way to only edit the scripts like manifest in an apk file?
I need to paste some lines into the script..

Comment: in APK u can't change anything. :P

Comment: @MD has a point, but still, my gut says you'll be able to open it like any other archive and edit the script file. Doesn't guarantee it'll work though.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: @shyam What i knew is you can see the all `manifest.xml` but you can't edit it. I already worked in my one of app.

Comment: even if it works, he would have to use signer for apk which it wouldn't be the original

Comment: @VaishaliSharma actually you can modify apk

Answer (score 8):

I was digging for hours. This is the tool that I used in the end:
https://github.com/WindySha/ManifestEditor

I had to to use slightly different AndroidManifest.xml settings for different environments. Decompiling and compiling again with apktool was really slowing down CI/CD process so ManifestEditor was life saver. It is based on [AXMLEditor](https://github.com/fourbrother/AXMLEditor).

Comment: I would like to know how did you edit those manifest. I've tried with the option -up but the resulting file ended up being even smaller than the original, which makes me guess that I should supply ALL permissions. And that put another question in the table... ¿what happend with special user permissions like uses-permission-sdk-23?

Cand you put any light?

Answer (score 4):

There exist tools for decompiling and then rebuilding APKs, such as apktool: http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/

Comment: But this tool is buggy and decompiles not all APKs, and bugs are not fixed for years. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: @Vitalii +1. It crashed now on unpacking Tiktok.